# HTML Errors in DreamWeaver?

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I'm getting errors starting with line 15:"Document does not allow element tr here". If I get rid of it, my chart is messed up. Did I miss or add too many tr somewhere? Of course I'll keep looking and if I find something I will post it. I was almost positive I watched my starting and ending points..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Jake's Schedule</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Jacob Martin</h1>
        <h3>This table shows my Fall Semester of classes</h3>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Hometown:</b> Pulaski, WI<br />I have lived there for 19 years</td>
                <td><b><u>Education:</u></b> Soon to have Associates for CS<br />UW Fox Valley 2015 for Associates<br/>BA at UW Stout</td>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2"><h2>My Favorites</h2><br/> 
                    <ol>
                        <li><h3>Musicians</h3></li>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Limp Bizkit</li>
                                <li>Kid Rock</li>
                            </ul>
                        <li><h3>Hobbies</h3></li>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Running</li>
                                <li>Video Games</li>
                            </ul>
                        <li><h3>Websites</h3></li>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href=http://www.ign.com>IGN</a></li>
                                <li><a href=http://n4g.com>N4G</a></li>
                                <li><a href=http://www.wwe.com/wwenetwork>WWE Network</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </ol>
                </td>
                <td><table border="2">
            <tr>
                <th> </th>
                <th>Monday</th>
                <th>Tuesday</th>
                <th>Wednesday</th>
                <th>Thursday</th>
                <th>Friday</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>8:00-<br/>8:59</th>
                <td>Ethics</td>
                <td rowspan="2">Data Structors</td>
                <td>Ethics</td>
                <td rowspan="2">Data Structors</td>
                <td>Ethics</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>9:00-<br/>9:59</th>
                <td>study</td>
                <td>study</td>
                <td>study</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>10:00-<br/>10:59</th>
                <td colspan="5">Calculas II</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>11:00-<br/>11:59</th>
                <td colspan="5">study</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>12:00-<br/>12:59</th>
                <td colspan="5">study</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>1:00-<br/>1:59</th>
                <td colspan="5">study</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>2:00-<br/>2:59</th>
                <td colspan="5">study</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>3:00-<br/>3:59</th>
                <td>Linear Algebra</td>
                <td>study</td>
                <td>Linear Algebra</td>
                <td>study</td>
                <td>Linear Algebra</td>
            </tr>
            </tr>
        </table></td>
            </tr>

                <td colspan="2"> <p>My goals goals for this Summer is to learn how to make webpages with HTML.<br/> I also want to learn more about Computer Programming in general.<br/> I have 4 classes and I want to be ready for my website job this fall.</p></td>

        </table>

        <img src="future.jpg" alt="The Future" style="width:400px;height:200px;"/>

        <p>a&#178; + b&#178; = c&#178;</p>
        <p>&#189; &#62; &#188; &amp; 0&#176; C &#60; 33&#176; F</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first two table rows are missing the close /tr tag.

Dreamweaver is encountering a new tr tag on line 15 without the previous tr tag being close. It also happens again on line 40.

Answer (score 3):

you have missed one  closed bracket of `<tr>`. put  here.

```
<td colspan="2">
 <p>My goals goals for this Summer is to learn how to make webpages with HTML.<br/> I also want to learn more about Computer Programming 
in  general.<br/> I have 4 classes and I want to be ready for my website job this  fall.</p></td>

</tr>

    </table>
```